# boost::mpl::for_each without instantiating

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mpl

Taking the following example, I wonder whether there is an alternative to `boost::mpl::for_each`, which does call a Functor without any arguments.

```
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>

struct EasyFixEngineA { static const char* const name() { return "a"; } };
struct EasyFixEngineB { static const char* const name() { return "b"; } };

struct Registrator {
    // Would prefer a template<class T> void operator()()
    template<class T> void operator()(T t) {
        RegisterInFactory<EasyFixEngine, T> dummy(T::name());
    }
};

// ...
typedef boost::mpl::vector<EasyFixEngineA,EasyFixEngineB> Engines;
boost::mpl::for_each<Engines>(Registrator());
```

It seems like `for_each` is default-instantiating the types.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `boost::type` and `mpl::_` to create an MPL lambda that transforms each type in the list before instantiating the elements and calling the function, like this:

```
mpl::for_each<Engines, boost::type<mpl::_> >(Registrator());
```

`Registrator` should look something like this:

```
struct Registrator
{
  template<typename T>
  void operator()(boost::type<T>) const
  {
      RegisterInFactory<EasyFixEngine, T> dummy(T::name());
  }
};
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the three parameter for_each:

```
mpl::for_each<Engines,mpl::single_view>(Registrator())
```

Then the instances you get will be of `single_view`.

Comment: The code sadly does not work. I also cannot find any example how to properly use `single_view`.

Comment: Besides it seems like you are passing a partial typed template, only.