# Which library does boost::type belong to?

Tags: c++, boost

I was trying to solve a problem with `boost::mpl::for_each`, when I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954220/boostmplfor-each-without-instantiating). The answer mentions a type named `boost::type`. It works well if I include `<boost/type.hpp>`. My question is, which Boost library it belongs to? Is it documented anywhere? While it really is just a dumb empty template, I guess it should have a documentation somewhere if it is in the main `boost` namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the boost github repository `<boost/type.hpp>` is located in the submodule `core`:

https://github.com/boostorg/core

https://github.com/boostorg/core/blob/master/include/boost/type.hpp

So it seems to be part of the [Boost Core library](http://boostorg.github.io/core/), however there seems to be no documentation available for this specific file.